# How to override record table naming to access existing data in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, orchardcms

I need to access data from pre-existing tables.  I've started working my way through creating a module to display the data etc.  However, Orchard is prefixing the table commands with the 'Table_Prefix' and 'Module Name'.

Is there any way I can specify what table to bind the model, so that I can use the existing IRepository

I'm trying to steer clear of modifying the core code, or implement my own IRepository  ( which I've got a feeling is what I'm going to have to do.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Which table data do you want to access, and why? Orchard is done in a way you do not even need to know there is an SQL table underneath for most usages, and provides services to access most contents as CLR objects, not as table rows.

Comment: As stated in the question, I need to access existing data.  I appreciate I'm working via an ORM.  Having looked at the source, I can see that the binding is done via Fluent NHibernate!s automap which works by convention.  I've found another similar question from the Orchard Forum which states that the only way is to create a DAL for the external data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom table naming convention (so that it would fit your current naming) by altering the core code, in three ways:

1. Record name mapping is created in `BuildRecord` method of
   `CompositionStrategy` class
   (*Orchard.Framework/Environment/ShellBuilders/CompositionStrategy*), so you can simply **modify the code here.**
2. By **altering the `Apply` method of `Orchard.Data.Conventions.RecordTableNameConvention`** class. This is where the record table name mappings (built in point 1.) get pushed to NHibernate.
3. **Create your own implementation of `FluentNHibernate.Conventions.IClassConvention`** (similar to `RecordTableNameConvention` mentioned above and replace the default one used by `AutoMap` in `Orchard.Data.Providers.AbstractDataServicesProvider`'s `CreatePersistenceModel(...)` method with it.

You could also create your own `IDataServicesProvider` implementation, but that would surely be an overkill if you only need to change the table naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I ended up using my own repository in the end because I was dealing with tables with a different naming convention to that used by automapping part Orchard.  However I might need to take this approach on another project I might be doing in Orchard.

Answer (score 0):

I was modifying CompositionStrategy and discovered that you have to modify the following

**1. SetupService.cs (Modules\Orchard.Setup\Services):**

Tables hardcoded in the Setup method are
"Orchard_Framework_DataMigrationRecord" and
"Settings_ShellDescriptorRecord"

**2. InfosetController.cs (Modules\Upgrade\Controllers):**

Multiple tables were hardcoded in this class which need to be updated.

**3. DataMigrationManager.cs (Data\Migration):**

Replace the SchemaBuilder parameters to the contructor.